# Resolving invalid workspace error

Tags: arcpy, workspace, error-000875

I have been using a third party ArcGIS tool called Landscape Fragmentation Tool.  I originally had some troubles getting it to work correctly.  Approximately 3 weeks ago I thought I had resolved those issues and understood how to prevent any error messages and an incomplete execution of the tool. 
However, I am now back in the position where I cannot make this tool work anymore.

I keep getting this error:

> Executing: Landscape_Fragmentation_Tool NLCD_reclass_bfpads1 90 C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\lfttestsat
>
> Start Time: Sat Oct 12 18:00:14 2013
>
> Running script Landscape_Fragmentation_Tool...
>
> OUTPUT DATASET NAME IS:
>   C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\lfttestsat
>
> DATA EXTRACTED FROM LAND COVER
>
> EDGE FRAGMENTATION IDENTIFIED
>
> INTERIOR, PATCH, AND PERFORATED FRAGMENTATION IDENTIFIED
>
> CATEGORIZING CORE FOREST PATCHES...
>
> File "C:\Users\Beth\Documents\Landscape_Fragmentation_SA\Landscape_Fragmentation_SA\LFT_SA_Arc10.py", line 334, in

```
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion (fragMap_6c, FragMap, "INTEGER")
```

> : ERROR 000875: Output raster: C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\lfttestsat's workspace is an invalid output workspace.
>
> ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters.
>
> Failed to execute (ASCIIToRaster).
>
> Completed script Landscape_Fragmentation_Tool...
>
> Failed to execute (Landscape_Fragmentation_Tool).
>
> Failed at Sat Oct 12 19:02:49 2013 (Elapsed Time: 1 hours 2 minutes 35 seconds)

The tool creates a temporary workspace folder and the intermediate steps are stored in this folder.

Answer (score 4):

Your error looks like it is here:

```
OUTPUT DATASET NAME IS:

C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\lfttestsat
```

It looks like it's concatenating the path to the gdb-

(`C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\`)

with the full path to the feature class-

(`C:\Users\Beth\Documents\ArcGIS\lftmod\landfragmod.gdb\lfttestsat`)

This is clearly an invalid path.

Without looking at the code (if it even is available to you), we can't determine how the paths are being joined and how to go about solving this. I notice that this script took an hour to run, so you should test this tool on a much smaller dataset so that way you aren't waiting so long for a potential failure.